# F# interactive vs. F# solution and WCF

Tags: wcf, f#, f#-interactive

Try to run this in F# interactive:

```
#r "System.ServiceModel"
#r "System.Runtime.Serialization"

open System.ServiceModel

[<ServiceContract>]
type IWCF =
  [<OperationContract>]
  abstract Ping: float -> unit

type WCF () =
  interface IWCF with
    member o.Ping a = printfn "Hello, %g" a

let svh = new ServiceHost (typeof<WCF>)
```

You will probably succeed. Try to make a new solution.

Reference:

- System.Runtime.Serialization
- System.ServiceModel

Paste the following code into `Program.fs`:

```
open System.ServiceModel

[<ServiceContract>]
type IWCF =
  [<OperationContract>]
  abstract Ping: float -> unit

type WCF () =
  interface IWCF with
    member o.Ping a = printfn "Hello, %g" a

let svh = new ServiceHost (typeof<WCF>)
```

And run it. I get the following error:

> All parameter names used in operations that make up a service contract must not be null. Parameter name: name

What is wrong?

PS: I use Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate SP1

EDIT: just to make sure, the C# equivalent works fine

Comment: Have you doubled-checked to make sure you're targeting the right version of .NET run-time? As I recall, the default for F# console applications, in VS 2010, is the .NET 4 Client Profile, which is *not* the full .NET profile, which sometimes causes these sort of "it works here but not there" types of issues.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is indeed that you need to have names for the parameters in WCF-Operations.

Here is a solution to get named parameters in there (named it `a` just like you did) - as to why it is working in F#-Interactive? No clue, maybe it puts some standardnames for parameters in there.
The syntax is slightly strange but you can define names for the parameters in F#, try:

```
[<ServiceContract>]
type IWCF =
  [<OperationContract>]
  abstract member Ping: a:float -> unit
```

NOTE: I don't know if you need the `member` in there but I just checked some of my files and did put it in there. I have no compiler around ATM so I will let it sit there in case you really need it (but I don't think so)

Comment: Thanks, that helped! I did not know that parameters of interface members can have names as well.

Answer (score 1):

I know this issue has been marked as answered, but I came across the same exception message, for a completely different reason. I just post in case someone else experience the same problem with the same cause I had.

In my case, I used dotNET_Reactor to obfuscate my service.exe with the flags '-exclude_types 1 -necrobit 1 -mapping_file 1' in addition to -file and -targetfile.

I haven't tracked down the actual "why" it didn't work, but removing the obfuscation helped. It was quite frustrating knowing everything worked from visual studio, but installing the application (which was obfuscated by the build server) on the same machine failed when starting the service.

Bjørnar Sundsbø